# Convert from A1 notation to a string/list notation?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm attempting to write a script to protect all of a sheet from edits, except for a couple of sections. I currently get the error "Cannot convert Array to Range[]."

I am currently under the impression that I need to write it in a string notation (I thinks that's what it's called) such as (4,3,3,2) for ['C4:D7'] in the format (firstRow, firstColumn, Number of Rows, Number of Columns) as I currently understand it.

this is the script currently:

```
function Protect() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var protection = spreadsheet.protect();
  protection.setUnprotectedRanges(['C4:D7', 'C11:D13', 'C18:E20', 'F18:G18', 'C23:G25', 'C30:D32'])
};
```

> So my main question is what should my line 4 be because nothing I have tried works, (and if you use an example can I request that you use an actual example because i find that I really struggle to get what to do when people use placeholders in their answers)

and a sort of sub question is: Is there a way to convert from A1 to string notation (sort of a reverse)?

Comment: About the error, how about modifying to ``protection.setu.setUnprotectedRanges(spreadsheet.getRangeList(['C4:D7', 'C11:D13', 'C18:E20', 'F18:G18', 'C23:G25', 'C30:D32']).getRanges())``? The document of ``getRangeList()`` is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRangeList(String)). By the way, as 2nd question, do you want to convert a1Notation to GridRange like [this](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/95c7cd650837f33a564babcaf013cae0)?

Comment: A list of range notation strings is different than an actual list of `Range` objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just to be clear:

As Tanaike said:

```
function Protect() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var protection = spreadsheet.protect();
  protection.setUnprotectedRanges(spreadsheet.getRangeList(['C4:D7', 'C11:D13', 'C18:E20', 'F18:G18', 'C23:G25', 'C30:D32']).getRanges());
}
```

And the Protect Ranges Dialog Confirms the Process worked:

[image]

**A possible answer to sub question:**

```
function convertA1ToList(A1string) {
  var A1string=A1string || 'A1:Z100';//for debugging return for this is 1,1,100,26
  if(A1string) {
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
    var rg=sh.getRange(A1string);
    var rowStart=rg.getRow();
    var columnStart=rg.getColumn();
    var numrows=rg.getHeight();
    var numcols=rg.getWidth();
    return Utilities.formatString('%s,%s,%s,%s',rowStart,columnStart,numrows,numcols);      
  }
}
```